# ALM Test Resource Datatable to UFT Syntax

Tags: syntax, vbscript, syntax-error

'Add a new sheet called Contributor
Datatable.AddSheet "Contributor"

'Import the sheet from ALM
Datatable.ImportSheet "[QualityCenter\Resources] Resources\DataTable\GUI Automation" , "ContributorAccount" , "Contributor"

Username = (Datatable.Value("Username" , "Contributor"))
Password = (Datatable.Value("Password" , "Contributor"))

Comment: This is what I have used in the past, and it is not working now.  ALM 11.5 & UFT 11.52.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue too. Instead of DataTable.value, Datatable("Username","Contributor") would work. I can say this coz that worked for me when Datatable.value didnt.